# How to add value in path Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to add value path in neo4j graph
such as (United States - Population - 2015) this path has value 320,970,000
and I want store in database

This is what i want
[image: Picture]

Can anyone help me? or any suggestion?

Comment: I'd set the properties on the nodes. Do something like setting a `value` property on the Population node to 320970000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @nicole and @cybersam have indicated, the value can be stored on Population and FertilityRate nodes. 
It can also be stored directly on the relationships between the country and year ***if*** the Population and FertilityRate have no real use in the graph except to carry their values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like @nicolewhite mentioned, you can store the values in `Population` and `FertilityRate` nodes.

For example, you can do something like this (I assume that the "US" and 2015 nodes already exist):

```
 MATCH (us:Country {name: "US"}), (y2015:Year {value: 2015})
 CREATE
   (us)<-[:OF_COUNTRY]-(:Population {value: 320970000})-[:DURING]->(y2015),
   (us)<-[:OF_COUNTRY]-(:FertilityRate {value: 1.86})-[:DURING]->(y2015);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remodel your graph to look like:

[image]

in order to reuse labels and values for the different dimensions and facts.

I omitted relationship types in the diagram.

Comment: oke thanks for your solution, but I want to make question answering system from this graph. Can this graph detect the word from user question input such as "how much population in US?" so it can automatically answer from this graph

Comment: The language parsing is going to be a different type of problem, but this structure can grow with synonyms for the fact, related words for the measure, etc. You can approach that problem in several ways, and it depends on how much data you have and how will the questions flow into the system.